# Ubuntu 22.04 on HP Zbook Studio G9 laptop

Tags: 22.04, hp

[Ubuntu for ZBook Studio G8/G9](https://ubuntu.com/certified/202201-29844) explains an OEM pre-installed 20.04 installation.  Has anyone successfully installed non-OEM 22.04 on a HP Zbook Studio G9 laptop?  If the OEM kernel and drivers are required, how does one get these?  The unit came pre-configured with MS Windows 11.  I intend to remove the SSD -- untouched -- install an unformatted new SSD of larger storage capacity that is supported by the machine, and do a fresh install of 22.04 current.  I have the HP service and parts manual and the necessary tools and experience to replace the SSD (or any other components).

Comment: You know certain Ubuntu ISOs contain the OEM kernels etc already included; and the installer will automatically use them where appropriate for your hardware (*if you're using an ISO that contains the OEM features, you didn't specify which 22.04 product you're wanting to use for example*)

Comment: I download the "stock" ISO release from Ubuntu, install that onto a bootable USB "stick", boot the computer into the BIOS dialog that allows me to select booting from USB, then boot the USB "stick" into the standalone "evaluate/try" Ubuntu to verify that the computer indeed can run under Ubuntu (currently, 22.04, always LTS not enthusiast).  If everything "works" (test audio, on board camera, IEEE 802.11, etc), then proceed to install that is another choice rather than test/evaluate.   Does the "stock" ISO have the OEM kernels/drivers?

Comment: You'll have to define what you mean by *stock* ISO as I'm unfamiliar with it, and if I go to the ISO tracker (http://iso.qa.ubuntu.com/) I'll find 12+ ISOs created today and none are labelled *stock*. For the recent Ubuntu 23.04 release, there are two ISOs listed for Ubuntu 23.04 Desktop for just *amd64*, one for Ubuntu 23.04 Server for *amd64*, plus numerous other *flavors* for that architecture & for other architectures. We have choice of product (Server, Desktop, *flavors*), architecture (*amd64*, *arm64*, *ppc64el*, *s390x*, *armhf*, etc) & for some choice of ISO & thus installer too

Comment: "stock: is the standard ISO download that appears by default; it is not a distro name for any distro.  For Ubuntu 22.04 the URL is https://ubuntu.com/download/desktop/thank-you?version=22.04.2&architecture=amd64  whereas any HP laptop OEM version is not revealed, nor is it listed in the "choices" you provided all of which are "stock" for the particular use (server, desktop, etc.)  and instruction set architecture (amd64, arm64, etc.).  Is it now clear what I mean by "stock".   HP, Dell, whatever OEM ISO versions are not "stock" but modified for specific vendor hardware/firmware configurations.